Is yielding a future from an contextlib asynccontextmanager unsafe?
I have a problem where I need to check that something's occurred in the log file between two points in execution.
Currently I do this:
print("start")
# do something here
print("end")
res = await check_log(...) # check in the log if something's happened 
                        # between start and end and return the line if so

I'm wondering if I can instead have a contextlib asynccontextmanager that looks like this:
class foo():
    def __init__(self, ...):
    ...

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def bar(self):
        print("start")
        fut = asyncio.Future()
        yield fut
        print("end")
        res = await check_log(...)
        fut.set_result(res)

and which I call like this, where the class contains variables I would otherwise have to pass to check_log:
obj = foo(...)

async with obj.bar() as b:
    # do something here

res = b.result()

Is there anything fundamentally unsafe or wrong about this? If so, is there a better way of doing this? I know with a regular context manager you can get around it by setting an attribute though I'm not sure it's possible with contextlib.

idk if I understood right, here's my understanding of what you are trying to: 1. writes log while program's running; 2. before termination, read log and see if anything notable happened and want to return the line with first occurance, did I guess correct? And what asyncio.Future will be?

I think you mean aynsc with obj.bar() as b:. When you check the log how can you tell that a log entry was made between entering and exiting the context manager? Also, you might want to look at PEP 8 – Style Guide for Python Code.

@jupiterbjy yes, that's what I'm intending to do. I have the method to check the log as the program executes, I was really just wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it with a context manager or something similar

@Booboo ah yes, my bad! The "Start" and "End" (or similar) gets written to the log which act as indicators for the check_log function. I'm currently doing this simply before and after the code I'm interested in, I was really just interested in whether a context manager could be used instead to manage the before and after bits.

Yes, you can use a context manager.

Yeah I get that, I just wasn't able to find an example of someone yielding a future and that setting the result after the fact and wondered if it was known to be bad practice.

What is the point of making b a Future? It is not awaited, it just holds a value. A plain variable could do that just as well.

This looks perfectly valid and ok.
The fundamental thing to keep in mind is that execution will only proceed in the code containing the with block after the __aexit__ method in the context manager is executed - which means running the part past the yield fut in your method, and therefore, the completion of the the await check_log(...) execution.
If you want check_log to perform concurrently with the block after the with block, that is equally as easy to do by changing creating check_log as a task, and setting its done callback to a function that will set fut's result - then, in this example, b could be awaited whenever one would like to check that result. Otherwise, it is good as is. (Just, please, put that yield statement and the block after it in a try-finally compound).
Of course, note that if someone tries to await b inside the with block, your code will be dead-locked.
If you have some value that the code post- with can get with no side-effects, you could use a contextvar.ContextVars as a class attribute of foo:
import contextvars

class foo():
    last_log = contextvars.ContextVar("last_log")
    def __init__(self, ...):
    ...

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def bar(self):
        print("start")
        try:
            yield None
        finally:
            print("end")
            self.last_log.set(await check_log(...))
...

obj = foo(...)

async with obj.bar():
    # do something here

res = obj.last_log.get()



Ah, I hadn't actually come across contextVar before, looks like exactly what I need. Thanks!

yes - despite the docs recommendation to create them as module-toplevel objects, I often prefer placing them as a class attribute, like in this example. They are just created once, so, no memory leaks, and are namespaced where they will be used.
